# Unsupported operand type for unicode error in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in the below format:

```
    Timestamp                     Clientip
    2015-07-22T02:40:06.499174Z   106.51.235.133    
    2015-07-22T02:40:06.632589Z   115.250.16.146
```

To sessionize the above data, I grouped it based on clientip and then created a session number field.

```
    dfgrouped = testdf.groupby(['clientip'])
    testdf['session_number'] = dfgrouped['timestamp'].apply(lambda s: (s - s.shift(1) > pd.Timedelta("15 min")).fillna(0).cumsum(skipna=False))
```

When i run the second command, I get the error "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'unicode'"

Not sure what is making things wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it appears that your timestamp is actually a string representation of a timestamp

Comment: So should i convert it to some format to do this processing?

Comment: Which Python version do you use?

Comment: Python version 1.6

Comment: 1.6 you probably mean your pandas version. @ppasler asking whether python 2.7 or 3.x

Comment: Sorry yeah i meant that. using python 2.7

Comment: You want to have a unix timestamp (float)?

Comment: I am not sure on what timestamp should I have. I am trying to convert that column to a format so that i can apply my function on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [162]: df
Out[162]:
                     Timestamp        Clientip
0  2015-07-22T02:40:06.499174Z  106.51.235.133
1  2015-07-22T02:50:06.000000Z  106.51.235.133
2  2015-07-22T02:40:06.632589Z  115.250.16.146
3  2015-07-22T03:30:16.111111Z  115.250.16.146

In [163]: df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp, errors='coerce')

In [164]: df
Out[164]:
                   Timestamp        Clientip
0 2015-07-22 02:40:06.499174  106.51.235.133
1 2015-07-22 02:50:06.000000  106.51.235.133
2 2015-07-22 02:40:06.632589  115.250.16.146
3 2015-07-22 03:30:16.111111  115.250.16.146

In [165]: df.groupby('Clientip')['Timestamp'].apply(lambda s: (s - s.shift(1) > pd.Timedelta("15 min")).fillna(0).cumsum(skipna=False))
Out[165]:
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
Name: Timestamp, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamps are [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted strings with microsecond precision (as should be produced with [datetime.isoformat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat)). They're also in unicode form (Python 3 calls those strings) but contain only ASCII. With an appropriate format string you could parse them with [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime). In Pandas, the appropriate function is called [to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#converting-to-timestamps).